# Setting Email Notification for Virtual machine whic are down or services that are stopped in Azure Cloud

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, email-notifications

We have more than 10 virtual machines in our cloud environment.there are some duration during which our virtual machine get stopped or the services get automatically stopped. We tried with creating rules, but it only works for a particular threshold. I want to set email notifications, if any of the virtual machine is down, or services get stopped. is it possible in the azure cloud environment.

Comment: that's not a programming question, but an administration question. There's different stackExchange pages for that.

Comment: Can someone move this question to the relevant section or redirect me to a page, where this question can be answered.

Comment: asking for an off-site ressource is also deprecated here on stack overflow ;) but seriously, try the "stackExchange" button in the upper right corner and search for "server".